# Posting topic on Facebook Groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I would like to know whether it is possible to post "topics for Discussion" on Facebook Groups by using either the old Rest API or Graph API? I somehow was unable to find any function within the API which would help me to do so.

Any work around or alternate solution to the above problem is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the instructions in [Publishing to Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing) to do this. Facebook groups appear to respond to the same requests as personal profiles do, including the `/feed` endpoint. Try `POST`ing to a group's https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/feed endpoint with the `message` parameter set.

Comment: Yes, the documentation tells how to post comment on the the wall/feeds but what about "posting Discussion-topics" inside groups??

Comment: I don't see any connections via introspection. http://graph.facebook.com/2204501798?metadata=1&access_token=2227470867|2.FisDNRtuJpkr1Kz4maUfzw__.3600.1273532400-70601113|GHipnqck7cbBAb3IGDkJGXAiPEg. Guessing you can't.